# how to use [PUT,UPDATE,DELETE] with multiple field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In this they get the snippet using pk,but i have to get by name, id and author. So how to write the functional view

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def snippet_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        snippet.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two (or more ways)
**Method - 1**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def snippet_detail(request):
    url_params = request.GET  # <<<<<<<<< Change <<<<<<<<<
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(**url_params)  # <<<<<<<<< Change <<<<<<<<<
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    # same code
```

In this method, your `urls.py` must be like this,

```
url(r'some_endpoint/',snippet_detail)
```

and api will be `host/end/point/some_endpoint/?id=123&name=testname&author=test_author`

**Method - 2**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def snippet_detail(request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(id=kwargs['id'], name=kwargs['name'], author=kwargs['author'])  # <<<<<<<<< Change <<<<<<<<<
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    # same code
```

and your `urls.py` will be like below,

```
url(r'some_endpoint/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<name>\w+)/(?P<author>\w+)/', snippet_detail)
```

and the end-point will be like, `host/end/point/some_endpoint/123/testname/test_author/`

**NOTE**
The problem with `method-2` is, you have to use the same url pattern for all http methods (in your case, `GET`,`PUT`,and `DELETE`)

Answer (score 0):

```
def snippet_detail(request, key, val):
    try:
        kw = {key:val}
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(**kw)
    except:
       //same logic
```

You would also need to update your urls.